# How to combine these two onPress functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am making a grade calculator app. I am using AsyncStorage to store my 'Classes' objects locally on my phone. When I click on one of the courses on my main.js screen, it will open another screen called courseDetails.js. There, there is a delete button which will, as expected, delete the object from the array where the objects are stored. My question is, I want my delete button to be able to perform `onPress={() => removeCourse(course.key)}` and `onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')`, so it deletes my object, and take me back to the home screen, but how do I combine them? They both work individually, but I can't get both of them to work at the same time... For more context, here is my `removeCourse()` function:

```
const removeCourse = (courseKey) => {
    console.log('remove course')
    newCourses = courses.filter((course) => {
        return course.key != courseKey
    });
    
    setCourses(newCourses);

    save(newCourses);
```

And here is `courseDetails.js` code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, } from 'react-native';
import { globalStyles } from '../styles/global';
import DetailCard from '../shared/detailCard';
import DeleteButton from '../shared/deleteButton';


export default function CourseDetails({navigation}){
    let course = navigation.getParam('course')
    let removeCourse = navigation.getParam('removeCourse')

    return(
        <View style={globalStyles.container}>
            <DetailCard>
                <Text >{course.course}</Text>
                <Text >{course.prof}</Text>
                {/* <Text >{navigation.getParam('gpa')}</Text> */}
            </DetailCard>
            <DeleteButton text='Delete Course' onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}/> //onPress in question
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried combining both in a single onPress callback, like this?

```
<DeleteButton text='Delete Course' onPress={() => {
    removeCourse(course.key);
    navigation.navigate('Home');
  }}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `useEffect` and include the courses as dependency in `useEffect`. Once there is something in courses deleted, `useEffect` is triggered and in there you can instruct react to navigate back to where you want to.